# django.contrib.registration.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator. Error while saving the user

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-registration, django-validation

I was creating a new user by the custom form with a custom author model inheriting default user model. I encountered this error while I was saving the user in the database.

Here are my all relevant files.

**blograms/settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for blograms project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'user.apps.UserConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blograms.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blograms.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.registration.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.registration.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.registration.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.registration.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**blograms/urls.py**

```
"""blograms URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from blograms import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('user/', include('user.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0])
```

**user/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import Http404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
import json


# Create your views here.

def webNew(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        author_form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
        result = {
            'error': []
        }

        if user_form.is_valid() and author_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()

                author = author_form.save(commit=False)
                author.author = user

                author.save()
                authenticate(request,username=user.username,password=user.password)
                login(request, user)
                result['success'] = True
        else:
                result['success'] = False
                for k,v in user_form.errors.items():
                    result['error'].extend(v)
                for k,v in author_form.errors.items():
                    result['error'].extend(v)

        # except Exception as e:
        #     result['success'] = False
        #     if hasattr(e, 'message'):
        #         result['error'] = e.message
        #     else:
        #         result['error'] = ['Something went Wrong']
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")


def webProfile(request, username=''):
    if username is not '':
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            # TODO: Follower logic
            return render(request, 'user/profile.html', {'vuser': user})
        except Exception as e:
            return Http404
    return redirect('/')


def webLogin(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        result = {
            'error': []
        }
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                login(request, form.get_user())
                result['success'] = True
                result['error'] = 'None'
            except Exception as e:
                result['success'] = False
                if hasattr(e, 'message'):
                    result['error'] = e.message
                else:
                    result['error'] = ['Something went Wrong']
        else:
            result['success'] = False
        for k, v in form.errors.items():
            result['error'].extend(v)
        print(result)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")


def webLogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Author


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')


class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Author
        fields = ['phone']
```

**user/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path,include

from blograms import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('login/', views.webLogin, name='web_login'),
   path('logout/', views.webLogout, name='web_logout'),
   path('new/', views.webNew, name='web_login'),
   path('<str:username>/', views.webProfile, name="web_profile"),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0])
```

**blog/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from  django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from user.forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {
        'form': AuthenticationForm,
        'form1': UserForm(),
        'form2': AuthorForm()
    }
    if request.user.username is not '':
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        context['user'] = user
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html',context)
```

**templates/user/auth.html**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<div class="modal login-modal">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
        <header class="modal-card-head">
            <p class="modal-card-title">Let's Get Started</p>
            <button class="close-modal delete" aria-label="close"></button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-card-body">
            <div class="container notification is-hidden is-danger error"></div>
            <div class="cloumns is-inline-flex-desktop">
                <div class="column is-half">
                    <form id="login-form" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label class="label is-large">Login</label>
                        <div class="field">
                            <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                                {% render_field form.username class+="input login-username" placeholder+="Username" %}
                                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <p class="control has-icons-left">
                                {% render_field form.password class+="input login-password" placeholder+="Password" %}
                                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <button class="button is-success" type="submit">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="container column is-hidden-desktop has-text-centered is-size-5">OR</div>
                <div class="column is-half">
                    <form id="signup-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <label class="label is-large">Sign Up</label>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="field">
                            <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                                {% render_field form1.username class+="input signup-username" id+="signup-username" placeholder+="Username" %}
                                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                                {% render_field form1.email class+="input signup-email" placeholder+="Email" %}
                                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <p class="control has-icons-left">
                                {% render_field form1.password class+="input signup-password" id+="signup-password" placeholder+="Password" %}
                                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                                {% render_field form2.phone class+="input signup-phone" placeholder+="Phone" %}
                                <span class="icon is-small is-left">
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
    </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <button class="button is-success" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error Traceback**

```
Internal Server Error: /user/new/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 26, in get_password_validators
    klass = import_string(validator['NAME'])
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.registration'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/shritesh99/PycharmProjects/blograms/user/views.py", line 25, in webNew
    user.save()
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 68, in save
    password_validation.password_changed(self._password, self)
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 60, in password_changed
    password_validators = get_default_password_validators()
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 19, in get_default_password_validators
    return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
  File "/home/shritesh99/anaconda3/envs/all/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 29, in get_password_validators
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % validator['NAME'])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The module in NAME could not be imported: django.contrib.registration.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator. Check your AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting.
[06/Jun/2019 14:38:57] "POST /user/new/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17511
```

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Django 2.2, [password validations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#password-validation) resides in `django.contrib.auth` module. So update [**`AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS) like this:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```